# How to exclude a record with INNER/LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

There's a table called `order_flags` that I am trying to join with `orders` table with orders.id being the foreign key in `order_flags` as `order_fk`. All I need is to exclude an order whose foreign key record has value `7` set for 'order_flags.flag' field. The SQL that I am trying below returns empty records. I expect this to return all the records except for the one having 7 as value for flag field in order_flags table. Tables in the question are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT orders.id, 
       orders.po_number, 
       orders.payment_method, 
       order_flags.flag, 
       order_details.vendor_fk, 
       Max(order_details.estimated_shipped_date) AS estimated_shipped_date, 
       Max(back_orders.back_order_date)          AS back_order_date 
FROM   orders 
       INNER JOIN order_details 
               ON order_details.order_fk = orders.id 
       LEFT JOIN order_flags 
              ON order_flags.order_fk = orders.id 
       LEFT JOIN sku 
              ON sku.item_sku = order_details.sku 
       LEFT JOIN back_orders 
              ON back_orders.sku_fk = sku.id 
WHERE  orders.order_status = 'PL' 
       AND ( ( order_details.item_status = 'PL' ) 
              OR ( order_details.item_status = 'SN' ) ) 
       AND orders.placed_date >= '1969-07-03' 
       AND orders.flag_overdue_po = '1' 
       AND order_details.estimated_shipped_date != '0000-00-00' 
       AND order_details.vendor_fk NOT IN ( '57', '0', '72', '161' ) 
       AND order_flags.flag != '7' 
GROUP  BY orders.id, 
          order_details.vendor_fk
```

Comment: please post the table structure and your desired output its very hard to figure out what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Your question talks about 2 tables - there are 5 in your query - I suggest you start by building a query based on the 2 tables mentioned in the question to see if you get your expected result then add in all the other joins and conditions 1 at a time. OR you could add all table definitions, sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Umair, apology for not being descriptive about my objective. The table that I'm trying to join is shown in the edited table.

Comment: @P.Salmon, added the tables as suggested.

Comment: The reason we like such in text is that we cannot use images..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in a WHERE clause you mention a column from a LEFT JOINed table, you convert the join to INNER JOIN.

You have this.

```
   FROM   orders 
      ...
   LEFT JOIN order_flags 
          ON order_flags.order_fk = orders.id 
      ...   
   WHERE ...  order_flags.flag != '7'
```

Try moving the filter to the ON clause like this.

```
   FROM   orders 
      ...
   LEFT JOIN order_flags 
          ON order_flags.order_fk = orders.id 
         AND order_flags.flag != '7'
      ...   
   WHERE ...
```

Or try this...

```
 WHERE ... (order_flags.flag IS NULL OR order_flags.flag != '7')
```

Why does this happen? If no row from the left of the LEFT JOIN matches a row from the right, the resultset of the join has NULLs for the columns from the left. NULLs are weird. They're not equal to anything, and they're not unequal to anything.  So your WHERE filter eliminated lots of rows.

Comment: Please notice this: A large query like the one in your question is often hard for SO people to sort out. If you can strip it down, we'll have an easier time helping you. And, better yet, you may be able to figure out your own problem. Look up "rubber duck debugging."

Comment: O. Jones, WHERE ... (order_flags.flag IS NULL OR order_flags.flag != '7') works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, I understand the importance of striping the query down so that it helps not only SO but also me solve it.